# How to set up Solr configuration with DSE

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am new in Cassandra. I am trying to use Solr with DSE for search function. I am trying to create solr core on my table for that I am using below command.

```
dsetool create_core tradebees_dev.yf_product_books generateResources=true
```

But I am getting below error message:

```
You requested the core to be created with reindex=false. Preexisting data will not be searchable via DSE Search until you reindex.
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Type org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SimpleDateType is not supported with automatic Solr schema generation. Specify 'lenient: true' in your resource generation options to ignore unsupported columns.
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:665)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:303)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:294)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands.createOrReloadCore(SearchDseToolCommands.java:1117)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands.access$300(SearchDseToolCommands.java:88)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands$CreateCore.execute(SearchDseToolCommands.java:390)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.run(DseTool.java:274)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.run(DseTool.java:203)
    at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.main(DseTool.java:309)
```

After this I was trying so many option but not able to create core.

Comment: What DSE version are you using and what CQL type that field is? if you could paste tradebees_dev.yf_product_books table definition it would be great info.

Comment: @Bereng DSE Version :- 5.0.1   OpsCenter :- 6.0.1  Table Definition ::- CREATE TABLE tradebees_dev.yf_product_books (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    abstract text,
    author text,
    category_code text,
    cid_code text,
    clickcount int,
    combo_book_id int,
    created_at timestamp,
    currency_code text,
    dimensions text,
    edition text,
    editor text,
    freight_id int,
    generaleditor text,

Comment: illustrator text,
    imagepath text,
    inquirycount int,
    is_copyright text,
    is_orderallowed text,
    is_presale text,
    is_showlink text,
    is_showquantity text,
    isbn text,
    language_code text,
    longtitle text,
    market_code text,
    marketinglink text,
    marketplace_code text,
    medium_code text,

Comment: medium_code text,on_sell int,ordercount int,otherfield text,otherimg text,pages int,presale_date date,presale_price decimal,price decimal,pricetype_code text,pubcountry_code text,pubdate text,publisher_code text,quantity int,quantity_unit_code text,quantity_unit_size int,sales_status text,samplelink text,series text,sku text,status_code text,status_end_date date,status_related_price decimal,status_start_date date,thumb text,title text,translator text,unit text,updated_at timestamp,user_id int,weight float,weight_unit_code text,word_count text)

Comment: @Bereng Just check this ....any suggest some way to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Your fields of CQL type `date` will give you that error message as auto resource generation does not support that CQL field type yet.

You can change them to `timestamp` for them to work until a fix is released.

Comment: [root@DSE ~]# dsetool create_core keyspace_name.table_name generateResources=ture
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: invalid boolean value: ture
 at org.apache.solr.common.util.StrUtils.parseBool(StrUtils.java:236)
 at org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams.getBool(SolrParams.java:96)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands.createOrReloadCore(SearchDseToolCommands.java:1060)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands.access$300(SearchDse

Comment: ToolCommands.java:88)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands$CreateCore.execute(SearchDseToolCommands.java:390)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.run(DseTool.java:274)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.run(DseTool.java:203)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.main(DseTool.java:309)
[root@DSE ~]# dsetool create_core tradebees_dev.

Comment: yf_product_books generateResources=ture
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: invalid boolean value: ture
 at org.apache.solr.common.util.StrUtils.parseBool(StrUtils.java:236)
 at org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams.getBool(SolrParams.java:96)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands.createOrReloadCore(SearchDseToolCommands.java:1060)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands.access$300(SearchDseToolCommands.java:88)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands$Crea

Comment: teCore.execute(SearchDseToolCommands.java:390)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.run(DseTool.java:274)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.run(DseTool.java:203)
 at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.main(DseTool.java:309)
I changed date to timestamp but still getting same issue.

Comment: I am using IP address at place of localhost. Is it compulsory to create core inside some particular location.. Can you please also tell me that should i need to make any changes into configuration file.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: you typed `ture` instead of `true`. I changed all to `timestamp` in you schema and it worked for me.

Comment: @Berang Thanks for your help.. I am able to create core,schema and solrconfig resource.. But when I am trying to execute any solr query I am getting error message select * from yf_product_books where solr_query = 'author:Chandan' ;
ServerError: <Error from server: code=0000 [Server error] message="java.io.IOException: No shards available for ranges: [(2205014674981121837,2205014674981121837]]">
Please help on this.

Comment: After creating core , only one custom index is created for SOLR_QUERY column.. So for example If i want to search by using title ,author columns then I have to create custom index on both columns ?

Comment: Even I tried by creating CUSTOM INDEX on columns but still getting same issue.  Please let me know How to resolve it..

Comment: If you are having trouble trying to run the product in it's most simple use case there might be sthg wrong. I suggest you contact Datastax support or experiment with one of the demos to familiarize yourself with how it works.